# UnhandledExceptionHandler on C# outside Visual Studio

Tags: c#, exception, logging

First of all: I looked at all similar questions at SO and no one answer does not helped.
I tried all three options (`Automatic, Catch, Throw`). In all results in the exact same behavior.
`ThreadException` doest not helped.

There is a project. A big one. The authorities, after more than 40k lines of code decided to add logging. Normal, the level of Debug, has already been added, now the sequence of Exception has come.

There is a variant to add everywhere `try {} catch {log.write (message)}`, but, in my opinion, this is not the best option.

I tried to use `UnhandledExceptionHandler`, but outside the studio (and if simple to run without debugging) handler does not want to work.

**Question**: did anyone encounter such a thing and what can you advise in this case?

What need: intercept all (not only fatal) exceptions in the release and log them.

WinForms, .NET 2.0 (yes, things a so bad :)

I hang `Handler` in `Main` before `Application.Run (mainForm)`:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException + = UnhandledExceptionHandler;
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode (UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

Processing code

```
static void UnhandledExceptionHandler (object source, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
            {
                logger.Error ("Message:" + ((Exception) e.ExceptionObject) .Message);
                var st = new StackTrace (((Exception) e.ExceptionObject), true);
                for (int i = 0; i <st.FrameCount; i ++)
                {
                    var frame = st.GetFrame (i);
                    var method = frame.GetMethod ();
                    // if (method.DeclaringType.FullName.Contains ("AMT"))
                    {
                        logger.Error ("Source:" + method.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + method.Name);
                        logger.Error ("Line:" + frame.GetFileLineNumber ());
                    }
                }
            }
```

The code simply does not work out, as if it does not exist. In the VS, in debug mode, everything is fine - and a breakpoint inside this method can be put, and the log is written. As soon as I run .exe directly, seems like handler disappear.